# read Zip file over HTTP - java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, apache, http, zip

My Java server reads a Zip file from an Apache Server over HTTP URL.  The process is very slow and it takes about 6 hours to read the entire file.  Close to the end of the file it throws the exception below. If the file is read faster the exception does not occur.  There are no firewalls between the servers.  How can I fix this problem?

Exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:163)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
```

JVM info:

```
Java version: 1.6.0_34,Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_34-b34)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS-System: Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64,amd64
```

Java code to reproduce the error:

```
public void process(long sleepMillis, String fileUrl) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader buffReader = null;
    ZipInputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL inputFileURL = new URL(fileUrl);
        URLConnection con = inputFileURL.openConnection();
        is = new ZipInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            log("*** ZipEntry name:" + ze.getName() + ", size: "
                    + ze.getSize());
            int records = 0;
            String buffer;
            while ((buffer = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                records++;
                log("rec[" + records + "]" + buffer);
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            }
            log("total recs: " + records);
        }
    } finally {
        if (buffReader != null) {
            buffReader.close();
        }
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
    log("DONE");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you download the file first then start reading the file?

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately that's not allowed by company policy.